# A simple this context change example in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JS, and have read a lot about the quirk behaviour of the content changing of `this`, So I made a simplest example:

**HTML**

```
<button>button1</button>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var button1, getText

button1 = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0]

getText = function(){alert(this.textContent)}

button1.addEventListener('click', getText)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/e95ME/

But I can't see the context of `this` changed, since the code work. Anyone can change this code or give another simple example to show the quirk behaviour of content changing of `this`?

Comment: It's not a quirk, it's a fundamental feature.

Comment: If you're new to JS, please pick up the good habit of ending statements with semicolons.

Comment: @AtesGoral Or, just consistently write in a safe semicolon-free style; the above snippet isn't enough to say such coding techniques are (or aren't) used, but you're probably correct for "a beginner" although I dispute the ultimate claim.

Comment: @AtesGoral sorry for the semicolons, I was also play around with coffeescript and ruby

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the button is clicked, the event listener will set `this` to the DOM element itself.

It's as if your function is called like this:

```
getText.call(<button-element>, <event>)
```

Comment: Thanks Man, you really answer that I can't even put into word

Answer (score 2):

```
var button1, getText

button1 = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0]

getText = function(){alert(this.textContent)} // called in context of `button1`

button1.addEventListener('click', getText)

getText(); // called in context of `window`
```

When the window loads, it will say `undefined`, because there is no property `window.textContent`. When you click the button, it should say `button1` because it's being called in the context of the button.

Comment: good example, it seems that addEventListener function pass the context of current node to the callback function

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean this?

```
var button1, getText

button1 = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0]

getText = function() {
    this.textContent = "changed content";
}

button1.addEventListener('click', getText)
```

Comment: Yes, your answer is what I'm looking for